# Unable to access controller data in codeigniter views

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use the following code in my controller. But the data['msg'] is not being passed to the view file.

Code:

```
class Operator{


public function view ($page)
{
    if ( ! file_exists('application/views/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
    {
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        show_404();
    }

    $data['title'] = $this->getTitle($page); 
    $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('pages/'.$page, $data);
    $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);

}
public function create_company()
{
        // some code
    $data['msg1']='my mesg';
    redirect('operator/view/operator_success','refresh');
}
};
```

When operator_success(view page) is loaded it show error message: variable '$msg1' not defined.

Comment: You have a typo: data['msg1']='my mesg'; => $data['msg1']='my mesg';

Comment: You'll probably want to check the scope of `$data` in your class `Operator`. You should be using a class variable. In addition, `Operator` should probably extend `CI_Controller`.

Comment: It's in addition impossible for the data to persist if you are doing a redirect unless you use sessions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Redirect you cannot use the variable or array. Instead setting the variable keep in session or CodeIgniter Flash Data.

```
class Operator
{

    public function view($page)
    {
        if (!file_exists('application/views/pages/' . $page . '.php')) {
            // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = $this->getTitle($page);
        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }

    public function create_company()
    {
        // some code
        $data['msg1'] = 'my mesg';

        // DO THIS 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('msg1', 'my mesg');
        // OR 
        $this->session->set_userdata('msg1', 'my mesg');
        redirect('operator/view/operator_success', 'refresh');
    }

}
```

After redirect you can simply call the flashdata.

```
echo $this->session->flashdata('msg1');
// OR
echo $this->session->userdata('msg1');
```

You must initialize the session before use, either autoload the session library or load manually.

[ 1 ] Autoload the session library (config/autoload.php)

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

[ 2 ] Manually load the library

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

see more about session and flash data [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html). Hope this helps you. Thanks!!

Comment: I am a newbie to CodeIg. What if a session is not set. will this create a new session? or what if a session is already set?..will it use the same session?

Comment: @Sarthak, I updated the answer. you must load the session library to use userdata or flashdata.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `data['msg1']` is set, then the page is redirected (not carrying the `data` array with it).

If you want `data` to persist, then you need to either use [sessions](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html) or [cookies](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/cookie_helper.html).

Answer (score 0):

you have redirect after setting variable so you must set this message either in session ("flash" message) or on operator/view/operator_success controller